# Triggering Matlab with DAQ toolbox MCC card

Tags: matlab

I need to collect data using Matlab and a MCC USB-2527 card.

Everything works except triggering. Here is my code:

```
BoardNR=1;
Chan=[0 1 2 3];
fs        = 100   
duration=60

ai        = analoginput('mcc',BoardNR);                                 
ch        = addchannel(ai,Chan);                                
set(ai,'SampleRate',fs);                                       
set(ai,'SamplesPerTrigger',duration*fs);                  
set(ai,'TriggerChannel',ch(3))                %Channel 3 is the position signal of a cyclic movement
set(ai,'TriggerType','Software')
set(ai,'TriggerCondition','Leaving')          %Should trigger when the position signal is not 0
set(ai,'TriggerConditionValue',[0,0])
set(ai,'TriggerDelay',1);
set(ai,'Timeout',5);


%The data collection is started
start(ai);
wait(ai, duration+1)

data=getdata(ai,fs*duration); 
plot(0.01:(1/fs):duration,data);             %Plotting real time vs signals
```

If I delete the parts with the triggering, I collect data perfectly. I need to trigger however, and when I run this code I get the error: "WAIT reached its timeout before OBJ stopped running" . I think this means that it stopped waiting for the triggering signal. I am 100 % positive that the position signal will be 0 every 20 seconds or so, so it should def. trigger.

I hope you can help. Ive tried everything, including having another TriggerCondition (like Entering, Rising, Falling) and another TriggerConditionValue.

Thanks in advance,

Henrik

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I reckon, you have to set the TriggerType to Manual. Which options are possible the command 'propinfo(ai.TriggerType)' should show.

I also use USB 2527 with MatLab ;-)